# A bounded random variable is sub-Gaussian, thus financial returns are not bounded?

Tags: statistics, statistical-finance

Bounded random variables are sub-Gaussian, yet I, intuitively, assume financial returns are bounded random variables; however, they are not sub-Gaussian. **Am I wrong to assume financial returns are bounded random variables? How could that be so?**

For a proof of bounded RV $\implies$ sub-Gaussian, see Example 2.4 on page 24 in Wainwright 2019 textbook, which is freely available online. [Ex 2.3 in Chapter 2 link here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf).

For a reminder on sub-Gaussian definition: a RV $X$ with $\mu = E_X [X]$ is sub-Gaussian if $\exists \sigma > 0 \ \text{s.t.} \ E[e^{\lambda (X-\mu)}] \leq e^{\sigma^2 \lambda^2 / 2}, \ \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}.$

Edit: To make sure I am not making a logical error here. The statement $P \implies Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \implies \lnot Q.$ Then we have that financial returns are not Gaussian implying that they are not bounded...I assume this is something that has been discussed by the literature?

Comment: "I, intuitively, assume financial returns are bounded random variables". Most financial theorists DO NOT make this assumption.